# Why is the console program interrupted when I Left-click on the console in VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, click, mouseevent, console-application

I write a console program in VS to respond to the mouse event. I want to print something when I click, so I write this code:

```
int keyPressed(int key){
return (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000 != 0);
}

void Mouse::click(){
while (1)
{
    if (keyPressed(VK_LBUTTON) || keyPressed(VK_RBUTTON)){
        cout << "click\n";
    }
}
}

int main(){
Mouse mouse;
while (1){
    mouse.click();
}
}
```

when I left-click, the "click" isn't printed, but if I press the keyboard or the right click, it is printed.

What is going on? How can I handle it? Thank you~

Comment: The right click has no problem.

Comment: I think it's because the left mouse is used to high light text, then you click the `Enter` key to copy selected text. The console output always stops when you click left mouse button, regardless of what is being done. Unrelated issue: `while(1)` loop is very inefficient, it tries to hijack the whole cpu core and go in circles. At least put `Sleep(10)` in there. But you really need a window program (create *"Win32 project"* instead of *"Win32 console project"*) to make a proper GUI program, [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx)

Comment: It is more explicitly done by clicking the icon on the upper left of the window caption > Edit > Mark.  Helpful to allow the user to copy/paste text from the console window.  Whether a simple mouse click automatically enters Edit mode is a setting.  Click the icon > Properties > Options tab > untick the "QuickEdit Mode" checkbox.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I understand. Thank you!

Comment: @HansPassant I works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`!=` has a higher precedence than `&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), thus the `0x8000 != 0` is being computed before the `&` takes effect.

Use parentheses -- change that line to this:

```
return (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000) != 0;
```

Comment: The result does not change. But I found that if I left-click on the place other than the console, it'll print "click".